# How to get values for each bar in json data?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to build a graph (using d3.js) with two bars per tick.

I'm not sure which structure is the best for working with the data, I've tried something like this:

```
var dataset = [
    {
        'month': 'Jan',
        'count': {
            'red': 29,
            'white': 32
        }
    },
    {
        'month': 'Feb',
        'count': {
            'red': 23,
            'white': 42
        }
    },
    {
        'month': 'Mar',
        'count': {
            'red': 34,
            'white': 47
        }
    }
];
```

How can I get the bars for each one?

I've tried this

```
function red(d, i) { return d[i]['red']; }

chart.selectAll('rect')
    .data(dataset, red)
   .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('width', 20)
    .attr('height', 100);
```

*(Don't mind the fact that I'm using fixed values for x, y, width and height. It's just an example.)*

Comment: dataset  json data is invalid, you missed single quote(') for "count" property.

Comment: Oh, missed that. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try putting each pair of bars in a `g` element. Something like this:

```
var groups = chart.selectAll('g')
    .data(dataset)
  .enter().append('g');

var reds = groups.append('rect')
    .datum(function(d) { return d.count.red; })
    .attr('class', 'red');

var whites = groups.append('rect')
    .datum(function(d) { return d.count.white; })
    .attr('class', 'white');
```